# How can I use the spread operator to copy a value of a key within the same variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I'm familiar with the spread operator documentation examples on MDN[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and think they are very clear about copying an arrays values into a new variable:

```
var parts = ['shoulders', 'knees']; 
var lyrics = ['head', ...parts, 'and', 'toes']; 
// ["head", "shoulders", "knees", "and", "toes"]
```

I want to know if I could apply the same principle to the following hash table, by only defining one variable:

```
const hashTable = {
  base: ['yieldToWorst', 'coupon', 'maturityDate'],
  muni: [...base, 'quantity', 'states'],
  corp: [...base, 'price'],
}
```

In this case `base` will not be defined when I attempted to use the spread operator, so I attempted the following:

```
const hashTable = {
  base: ['yieldToWorst', 'coupon', 'maturityDate'],
  muni: [hashTable['base'], 'quantity', 'states'],
  corp: [hashTable['base'], 'price'],
}
```

but this issue is that hasTable is not yet defined. Any solution to this, while containing all the code in one variable?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: No, just use another variable.

Comment: The spread notation is part of JavaScript syntax in various ways, but it's not an *operator*. That term refers to symbols and keywords that are part of the expression grammar.